# VBA pass argument to userform

Tags: excel, arguments, userform, vba

I have a userform which I wish to pass a range to. I have tried a couple of different ways to do it but does not seem to work.

Here is the sub code:

```html
Option Explicit

Sub Additional_Comments_Normal()
Dim MSG1 As Integer
Dim msg As String
Dim act As Range


On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'Calls userform

MSG1 = MsgBox("Would you like to add comments", vbYesNo, "Add comments")


If MSG1 = vbYes Then

With AddComments
On Error Resume Next
Set act = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please choose files you wish to add comments to", Type:=8)

If act Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub
End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    .Show
    
End With

Else
Exit Sub
End If

ErrHandler:

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
 msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
         & Err.Source & Chr(13) & Err.Description
MsgBox msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End If
End Sub
```

And the userform code is here:

```html
Public act As Range

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ctl As Control
Dim rng As Range
Dim MSG2 As Integer
Dim sfile As String


    If act.Column > 1 Then
        MsgBox ("Please choose File name from Column 1")
    Exit Sub
    End If

        If act.Row < 4 Then
            MsgBox ("Please choose a valid file")
        Exit Sub
        End If
         
            If Me.TxtComment.Value = "" Then
                MsgBox "Please add comments", vbExclamation, "Additional Comments"
                Me.TxtComment.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
            End If

            If Me.TxtName.Value = "" Then
                MsgBox "Please add your name", vbExclamation, "Additional Comments"
                Me.TxtName.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
            End If



MSG1 = MsgBox("Add Comments ?", vbYesNo, "Add comments")

If MSG1 = vbNo Then

End If

If MSG1 = vbYes Then

act.Offset(0, 16).Value = act.Offset(0, 16).Text & " " & Me.TxtComment.Value
act.Offset(0, 17).Value = act.Offset(0, 17).Text & " " & Me.TxtName.Value
 
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then
ctl.Value = ""
End If
Next ctl
      
AddComments.Hide

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

I then get an error about the act not being defined variable.

Can anyone shed some light on better process for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `Option Explicit` at the top of your code. That means that all variables need to be defined (which is considered good programming practice). So, you have two options to resolve this:

(1) Remove the line `Option Explicit`from your code or

(2) define all of your variables using the `Dim` command. In this case you'd have to add `Dim act as Range` to your Sub `CommandButton1_Click` on the form.

If you want to pass a variable to another sub then you can do so calling that sub with that variable like so:

`Call Additional_Comments_Normal(act)`

and the sub header neeeds to change like so:

```
Sub Additional_Comments_Normal(ByVal act as Range)

'(your code)'

End Sub
```

If "passing a variable to another sub" is too much trouble then you can also save the range somewhere in your file like so:

```
SomeHiddenSheet.Range("A1").Value2 = act
```

and in the other sub you can initiate act again:

```
act = SomeHiddenSheet.Range("A1").Value2
```

Comment: I went with Option 2, this brings up error 91, It does not recognise that I have defined Act in the sub.

Comment: You did not define it in the sub but outside. Still that should work.

Comment: I am trying to pass the range act to the userform, therefore the call procedure doesn't work the same way?

Comment: How would Excel know what `act` is unless you tell it what you want it to be. If you are wondering about the scope of various variables then you might want to consider reading this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-en/kb/141693/en

Comment: Hi Ralph, this is exactly my question to you I understand and have passed arguments between subs before when calling a new sub, this process doesn't work when passing to a userform, I have tried a method where you use the With Userform command and then Public declare the variable which from literature I have seen online apparently works, this method does not work for me hence me asking on here. So my questions is essentially asking what am I doing wrong in this script. http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=147329

Comment: @Samatar: simply move the line `Public act As Range` from the form to the module. `Public` variables need to be defined in modules. Alternatively, you can use this *Hidden Sheet* I mentioned within my answer.

Comment: I just checked and I think that Act was also used elsewhere in the workbook that's why it was not working. It is now working with the variable defined in the module. Thanks